# Personalizing My Postmates Delivery Experience (for better tips)

Tags: rest, postmates

I've found that one of the best ways to make extra tips driving for Postmates is to add a personal touch. For example, texting the classic `I haz Cheezburger` meme when I'm on the way with the food usually results in a better tip (mileage may vary).

Now, I am a lazy person and my only goal in life is to automate it. I figure that I just poll the [get delivery](https://postmates.com/developer/docs/endpoints#get_delivery) endpoint, wait for a state change that I'm out for delivery, sleep for a few minutes (so they aren't bombarded by notifications all at once), and then send my personal touch text with [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/sms). Simple program.

My problem is that this endpoint requires both a customer ID and a delivery ID. Since the only thing needed to [add a tip](https://postmates.com/developer/docs/endpoints#tip_delivery) is those two pieces of information, I'm going to take a guess that they are private info, unavailable to the driver...for some reason...

Is there an endpoint that drivers can query against? If I setup a REST endpoint, could I register it with your platform to get real-time delivery updates for my customers?